# Get the picture's name which is used as slide background

Tags: c#, vba, powerpoint, openxml, office-interop

I set a background of the second slide is a picture. And now I want to get this name of this picture.
I can get the name of picture in Word by using WordOpenXML. But in PowerPoint I don't know how to use it.

```
void picBackground()
{
    if (oPP.Slides[2].Background.Fill.Type==6)//check the background is a picture
    {
    // I want to get the name of this picture
    }
}
```

Sorry if my English is too bad.
Thanks for your watching.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I just wanted to check that you know that graphics files get renamed to a generic name when embedded in an Office file. So if you're trying to get the original graphic name, that won't work. The original name is only retained if the graphic has been linked instead of embedded.

Comment: If I insert a picture (name: abc.jpg) to a Word document. I can get the name of this picture through WordOpenXML. Ex: MessageBox.Show(_activeDoc.Shapes[i].TextFrame.TextRange.WordOpenXML)

Comment: Word <> PowerPoint

Comment: Yes, I know Word is different PP. So I don't know how to solve my problem and I hope anyone can help me.

Comment: As JohnK's already mentioned, unless the image is linked, the original file name is not retained. If you can persuade users to set the background picture using an add-in that you provide, the add-in could store the path to the picture file they've selected and other code could make use of that information.

Answer (score 0):

As John mentioned in the comments, when the image/picture is embedded, it is given a generic name. In PowerPoint, this is the case and there is no way to get the original name of the file even by using OpenXml.

If you want you can change the extension of a `pptx` file to a `zip`, and look at the contents, the picture will be in path `ppt/media/imageX.ext`such as `ppt/media/image1.png` and there will be no other information anywhere in the package about the original name of the image.

If you are creating these files, you can however store extra information within the file while inserting the image using a script, but there is no way to get this information for a regular image in a regular PowerPoint presentation file.